# importing templates to base templates in Django

Tags: html, django

I want to able to display `base.html` with my `gallery.html` in it. I inspected the source code with developer tools and gallery.html cannot be found when I'm on `http://localhost:8000/gallery/`

Note:

I have no `urls.py` in my gallery app currently. I only have a urls.py in my project directory.

urls.py for project:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from home.views import loadHomepage
from gallery.views import loadGallery
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'', 'home.views.loadHomepage'),
    url(r'gallery/$', 'home.views.loadGallery'),
)
```

gallery app views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def loadGallery(request):
    return render_to_response('gallery.html')
```

project structure

```
/proj
   /gallery
      /static
         /css
            gallery.css
      /templates
         gallery.html
   /proj
   /templates
      base.html
   /static
      /css
         base.css
```

base.html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="home-button">
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar">
      </div>
      <div class="content-container">
        {% block content %}

        {% endblock %}
      </div>

    </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
```

gallery.html:

```
{% extends base.html %}

{% block content %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/gallery-container.css" %}">
<div class="container">
hi there!
fgdfjkhlkjhjk
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)

STATICFILES_STORAGE = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
)

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)    

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', 'PersonalWebsiteAssets'))

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'home/templates'),    
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'gallery/templates'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'contact/templates'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'about/templates'),
)
```

Comment: where is the question?

Comment: Why are you splitting up your templates like this?

Comment: gallery is my `app` and I think this is organized for me

Comment: There are several errors in this template, so the fact that you are not seeing exceptions indicates that you are not actually rendering it at all. You should post your URLs and views.

Comment: @DanielRoseman jsut did this! thanks for teh suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your loadGallery view is being called at all. The previous URL, for loadHomepage, does not have any beginning/end anchors in the regex, so it will catch *all* URLs. Django's URL resolver will simply route everything there, and never proceed to the "gallery" URL.

You should make it as follows:

```
url(r'^$', 'home.views.loadHomepage'),
url(r'^gallery/$', 'home.views.loadGallery'),
```

at which point you will encounter the errors in the gallery template, such as the fact that the argument to the `extends` tag needs to be in quotes.

Comment: I fixed the gallery template quotes issue thanks! Now however I am getting `ViewDoesNotExist`error. Here is the traceback if youre interested http://dpaste.com/3EEE5KV/

Comment: So, is the view in home.views or gallery.views? Seems like it should be the latter.

Comment: I create a view in a `home` app to generate the `^$` page. There is another view in my gallery app as well that does the same thing. Both render_to_responses

Comment: Yes, so you need to make your URL point to the right one then.

Comment: I think this problem is due to the fact that when I go to `/gallery/`, the render_to_response('gallery.html') only generates the gallery.html. But my gallery.html extends `base.html` (home view). So I am not why it even needs to run the home view.

Comment: Argh, you're making this much more complicated than it needs to be. If your view is in gallery.views, then that's what your URL needs to point to, rather than home.views.loadGallery which (as the error message tells you) doesn't exist.

Comment: Sorry!! I just noticed this made the change and another view is generated! Sorry I didnt see this typo my mistake

Comment: Thank you for your help! Much appreciated! I like how you hinted me in the right direction haha sorry if i made things frustrating but I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to `{% load staticfiles %}` in all of your templates, regardless of whether or not you're inheriting from **base.html** (assuming you're using static files in the templates).

Your **urls.py** should also look something like:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^gallery/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name=gallery.html")),
)
```

Comment: So add `{% extends base.html %}` and `{% load staticfiles %}` to my gallery.html?

Comment: Yes...but I'm really not understanding why you're loading a stylesheet like that. You should probably create another `block` for `meta` or `links` in your base template, and use a `block.super` to include your gallery stylesheet in that template.

Comment: I'm new to django so I am a bit confused. Could you provide some sort of example please?

Comment: Have you updated your urls.py to display the template?

Comment: Do I need to do this? Currently in my urls.py for my project it includes `url(r'gallery/$', 'home.views.loadGallery'),` where `loadGallery` is a simple `return render_to_response('gallery.html')`